# Open APEX app outside my network

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have Oracle APEX installed on dB 12c on a linux box on my home network as a sandbox. When on this box I can open firefox and goto the below link and login fine.

http://oradev.attlocal.net:7172/apex/f?p=111:LOGIN_DESKTOP:23798986661662:::::

However on any other PC on my network, or outside my network I get page can not
be displayed. I use dyn up dater to translate my IP address to
www.aanning.com

this works fine for other applications, ie I use http://www.aanning.com:XXXX  (XXXX is a port#) and I can hit other apps (not oracle) on other PC on my network from outside, so I know this part works.

I have port 7172 forwarded to the APEX box and try the same link above
replacing oradev.attlocal.net  with www.aanning.com

but I get page can not be displayed.

How can I hit my APEX app from outside my network?
Please advise, thanks James

Comment: What APEX Listener do you use?

Comment: Hi, I think I "have it" now...I just can't test it myself, without leaving my house.   If someone can test and let me know?  It should come up with a login user id and password.  If you see that, I'm all in

Comment: http://www.aanning.com:7172/apex/f?p=111:LOGIN_DESKTOP:23798986661662:::::

Comment: http://www.aanning.com:7172/apex

Comment: If either of the above come up asking for login credentials...I'm good

Comment: It works, good job. Now please post the answer bellow for others to know too.

Comment: Add the answer as an actual answer, not a comment. It is perfectly OK to answer your own question and even marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, the APEX listener is set to port 7172.  use Dyn updater (dns updater) to forward your ISP's IP address to your domain (mine www.aanning.com).  Once done, you goto your routers port forwarding  and forward port 7172 to the APEX PC.  Oddly, I had done all of this, and it did not work.  I'm not sure what happened...it suddenly begin to work, for no apparent reason. The only thing I can think of, is I had reached the maximum number of ports I could forward on my router.  I deleted one I knew I was no longer using.  this is the only change I made, then it begin to work.